# Windows, профилировка сети

Tags: сеть

Есть 2 сервера арендованные у одного провайдера и в N моменты времени не получается отправить HTTP пакеты между ними. Сервера находятся в локальной сети, Web Server - IIS и бывает что нет ping между ними.

Как можно отловить проблему?
Или в чем она может быть?

Сервера на Windwos Server 2016

> Проблем скорее всего у провайдера, но ему это сложно доказать.

Comment: Если оба сервера в одной локальной сети, то почему они вообще у вас общаются через провайдера? Или они у вас физически разнесены, а локальная сеть поверх vpn?

Comment: Дебажить при помощи `wireshark`, читать логи систем, собирать статистику `ping` и `tracert`, отказаться от провайдера.

Comment: @Александр сервера арендованы у одного провайдера, но по tracerout они в локальной.

Answer (score 0):

Сканируйте и логируйте конкретный порт и его трафик. Хотя бы просто лог того, когда порт 80 (или какой вы там используете для HTTP пакетов общения между серверами) действует. Вычислите время, обратитесь к провайдеру, происходят ли какие изменения связанные с вашими серверами в это время. Смотрите логи своих систем на наличие проблем в это время и т.д..